# JavaScript style div based on another div's style [help]

Tags: javascript, html, css

why does this not work? I want to click a button to show the "nav", and then if the "nav" is blocked the "move" will be text-aligned to center.

I know I could just textAlign it the "move" with the same button, but that is not what I'm looking for.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
const move = document.getElementById('move');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (nav.style.display === "none") {
    nav.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    nav.style.display = "none";
  }
});

if (nav.style.display === "block") {
  move.style.textAlign = "center";
}
```

```css
#nav {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: none;
 } 
 
 li {
  display: inline;
 }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</div>


<div id="move">
  <h4>Hello</h4>
</div>
<button id="btn">change</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure if the question is really clear. I tried to help you with my answer below. Let me know if I understood correctly.

Comment: If you just add `move.style.textAlign = "center";` in the first `if` loop itself after making the nav `block`, instead of checking the condition again( if nav display === block), the same can be achieved . are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use, in this way you force the text inside #nav to be aligned in the center.

```
#nav {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

If you need to change the inline style dynamically based on some condition in javascript you could consider looking at the inline style of your dom node using `style` property ex: nav.style.display

A simple example:

```
if (nav.style.display === "none") {
    nav.style.display = "block";
    move.style.textAlign = "center";
  } else {
    nav.style.display = "none";
  }
```

More [info on style property can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Comment: i know how to do it with css, but I asked how to do it with javascript based upon another div's styling...

Comment: @hannacreed I made an edit to my answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
const move = document.getElementById('move');

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
const move = document.getElementById('move');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (nav.style.display === "none") {
    nav.style.display = "block";
    move.style.textAlign = "center";
  } else {
    nav.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Comment: for the most part, I thought it was possible to do it without that if statement within the button, but I suppose not.

Comment: So, you want a solution without `if (nav.style.display === "block") { move.style.textAlign = "center"; }` (last 3 lines from your original code)?

Comment: no, I just don't want that line of code put in the button, but I guess it has to be inside the button to work?

Comment: Yes, it should be inside the button. When you click button, you launch the code binded to that event. Any code that is not "inside" - is not "binded".